# Hibernate: Error Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm a newbie user of Hibernate. I've designed a database in MySQL and generated automatically the classes using HibernateTools. 
For each table, HibernateTools has created 2 classes, one representing the table itself, and the other the Home object with the persist. For instance the Users table has the Users.java and UsersHome.java

User.java

```
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer idUsuario;
private String nomUsuario;
private String mailUsuario;
private String pass;
private Date ultConexion;
private Date fechaAlta;
private Date ultimoIngreso;
private Date ultimoGasto;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private Set avisoses = new HashSet(0);
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private Set conceptoses = new HashSet(0);

public User() {
}

public User(String nomUsuario, String mailUsuario, String pass, Date ultConexion, Date fechaAlta) {
    this.nomUsuario = nomUsuario;
    this.mailUsuario = mailUsuario;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.ultConexion = ultConexion;
    this.fechaAlta = fechaAlta;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public User(String nomUsuario, String mailUsuario, String pass, Date ultConexion, Date fechaAlta,
        Date ultimoIngreso, Date ultimoGasto, Set avisoses, Set conceptoses) {
    this.nomUsuario = nomUsuario;
    this.mailUsuario = mailUsuario;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.ultConexion = ultConexion;
    this.fechaAlta = fechaAlta;
    this.ultimoIngreso = ultimoIngreso;
    this.ultimoGasto = ultimoGasto;
    this.avisoses = avisoses;
    this.conceptoses = conceptoses;
}

public Integer getIdUsuario() {
    return this.idUsuario;
}

public void setIdUsuario(Integer idUsuario) {
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
}

public String getNomUsuario() {
    return this.nomUsuario;
}

public void setNomUsuario(String nomUsuario) {
    this.nomUsuario = nomUsuario;
}

public String getMailUsuario() {
    return this.mailUsuario;
}

public void setMailUsuario(String mailUsuario) {
    this.mailUsuario = mailUsuario;
}

public String getPass() {
    return this.pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

public Date getUltConexion() {
    return this.ultConexion;
}

public void setUltConexion(Date ultConexion) {
    this.ultConexion = ultConexion;
}

public Date getFechaAlta() {
    return this.fechaAlta;
}

public void setFechaAlta(Date fechaAlta) {
    this.fechaAlta = fechaAlta;
}

public Date getUltimoIngreso() {
    return this.ultimoIngreso;
}

public void setUltimoIngreso(Date ultimoIngreso) {
    this.ultimoIngreso = ultimoIngreso;
}

public Date getUltimoGasto() {
    return this.ultimoGasto;
}

public void setUltimoGasto(Date ultimoGasto) {
    this.ultimoGasto = ultimoGasto;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Set getAvisoses() {
    return this.avisoses;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void setAvisoses(Set avisoses) {
    this.avisoses = avisoses;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Set getConceptoses() {
    return this.conceptoses;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void setConceptoses(Set conceptoses) {
    this.conceptoses = conceptoses;
}
```

UserHome.java

```
public class UserHome {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserHome.class);

private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();

protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    try {
        return (SessionFactory) new InitialContext().lookup("SessionFactory");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI", e);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI");
    }
}

public void persist(User transientInstance) {
    log.debug("persisting User instance");
    try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
        log.debug("persist successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("persist failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public void attachDirty(User instance) {
    log.debug("attaching dirty User instance");
    try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(instance);
        log.debug("attach successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("attach failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public void attachClean(User instance) {
    log.debug("attaching clean User instance");
    try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().lock(instance, LockMode.NONE);
        log.debug("attach successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("attach failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public void delete(User persistentInstance) {
    log.debug("deleting User instance");
    try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(persistentInstance);
        log.debug("delete successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("delete failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public User merge(User detachedInstance) {
    log.debug("merging User instance");
    try {
        User result = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(detachedInstance);
        log.debug("merge successful");
        return result;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("merge failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public User findById(java.lang.Integer id) {
    log.debug("getting User instance with id: " + id);
    try {
        User instance = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get("Usuario", id);
        if (instance == null) {
            log.debug("get successful, no instance found");
        } else {
            log.debug("get successful, instance found");
        }
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public List findByExample(User instance) {
    log.debug("finding User instance by example");
    try {
        List results = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria("User").add(Example.create(instance))
                .list();
        log.debug("find by example successful, result size: " + results.size());
        return results;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("find by example failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

}

When I do this as a tryout to see if everything goes as supposed, I get "Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI"

```
UserHome uh = new UserHome();
User u = new User("nom", "Mail1@mail.com", "chsss", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
uh.persist(u);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The complete stacktrace of the exception

```
abr 21, 2016 8:47:09 AM hibernate.UsuarioHome getSessionFactory
SEVERE: Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at hibernate.UserHome.getSessionFactory(UserHome.java:27)
at hibernate.UserHome.<init>(UserHome.java:23)
at bbdd.FirstHibernate.main(FirstHibernate.java:11)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI
at hibernate.UserHome.getSessionFactory(UserHome.java:30)
at hibernate.UserHome.<init>(UserHome.java:23)
at bbdd.FirstHibernate.main(FirstHibernate.java:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a initial context? Initial context will only exists when you are running your code on application server. If you are running this code on application server, please add your config files so that I can verify it is configured properly. If there is no application server and the code is being run from POJO, you need to get session factory in a different manner.Looking at your classes, I think you are running this in a POJO.

It will also help if you can paste the exception or stacktrace. Makes it easier to guess whats going wrong.

Comment: There is no application server, and yes the code is being run from POJO. I will update the initial post adding the exception, but I don't know how to get the session factory, it is supposed to do so when I run UserHome uh = new UserHome(); right?

Comment: Sorry I was out for a few days so delay is response. In Pojo, you dont have a JNDI or inital context. You need to use configuration object to get a session factory. SessionFactory ss = new Configuration(). configure("path to cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();